# Angular JS - Angular UI Router - Reloading current state based on location watch

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I created a navigation bar and when a user clicks a link that corresponds to the current state, nothing happens. For instance you are on `/about` and click the link About that have an `href="/about"`. The menu stays open. If you click on another link (e.g. different state), it works.

I read somewhere that the state transition is ignored if the current state is the same as the destination state. I even wonder if the state transition is started since the location does not change.

`menuItem.link` refers to regular URI like `/`, `/contact` or `/about`.

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen" ng-repeat="menu in menuModel">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
        {{menu.text}} <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menu.items"><a href="{{menuItem.link}}">{{menuItem.text}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I guess the menu stays open because the transition does not occur. Is there a way to force the transition even if it's on the same state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the URL to "`#/about`".. Angular UI Router by default adds a "`#`" in front of the URL

If that doesn't work, use this to detect what's happening:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
     console.log("To state is"+toState.name+", From State is "+fromState.name);
  });
```

You can see if the state change has started at all.

Edit:

If you want to check why the state change is not happening, use this snippet:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
   function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
     console.log('$stateChangeError', event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error);
  });
```

Edit - Resolution:
when you're in `/about` and then the `href` is `/about`, UI router looks for a child state about inside your /about state. What you want is for the URL to read "." just the dot represents the current state. If you want a better implementation, instead of using hrefs, you can use `ui-sref=".about"`.. eg. `<a ui-sref="home">Home</a> | <a ui-sref="about">About</a>` UI Router will automatically generate the relevant href and this would also solve your problem.

As you rightly mentioned in your comment, you might have to add additional params too - More details here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Comment: I enable html5Mode, so I don't need the `#`.

Comment: no transition is fired. I guess this is right because the location does not change

Comment: Ok cool.. that's fine let's analyse why that is. It is probably because the path is specified wrong. I've added a way to diagnose this.. Check it out.

Comment: Unfortunately no log comes from the `$stateChangeError`.

Comment: You can easily reproduce, just create a link with an href. Then when you are in the state, click again the link. You'll see that nothing happens

Comment: @Sydney Oh I get it now.. Ok when you're in /about and then the `href` is `/about`, UI router looks for a child state about inside your `/about` state.
What you want is for the URL to read "." just the dot represents the current state. If you want a better implementation, instead of using hrefs, you can use ui-sref=".about".. eg. `<a ui-sref="home">Home</a> | <a ui-sref="about">About</a>`

UI Router will automatically generate the relevant href and this would also solve your problem. If this works, I'll add this update this as the answer.

Comment: It works but I had to add the options `reload` like that `<a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-opts="{reload:true}">`. Please update the answer.

Comment: Oh cool. Yea the options are optional. I believe reload: true is set to false by default for the same state. I've updated the answer. Please mark this as answered! Thanks!